# How to install python 3.8 directly in /usr/bin?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, centos7

Trying to install python 3.8 from source in CentOS 7.9.

The default installed python is 2.7.5 and is located at /usr/bin.

```
sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel
sudo cd /opt
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.12/Python-3.8.12.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.8.12.tgz
cd Python-3.8.12
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make install
```

I thought `make install` would create `python3` in /usr/bin, but it didn't.

Comment: The answer from @minhuw is correct, however make sure this is what you really want. Once you install python that way, it's not trivial to cleanly update/remove it anymore. Unless you need specific options / patches, a package may be a better option. For example https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/rh-python38-python-3.8.0-15.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, CPython install compiled python binary in `/usr/local/bin/python`.  (source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/configure#L571) You may specify the prefix mannually as `configure --prefix=/usr`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set symlinks such as

```
$ sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8
$ sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip3.8
```

The above works great in CentOS7 after installing Python3.8 as noted above.